# A table with 2 columns where one column increases sequentially while the other column displaying the same number till a limit is reached

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to write a code where the users enters two numbers in order to get 2 columns. It is very hard to explain by words what I am trying to achieve so here is an example:

If the user inputs `a = 1` and `b = 1`, the following table should be created:

```
ans =

1    1
```

If the user inputs `a = 2` and `b = 2`:

```
ans =

1    1
1    2
2    1
2    2
```

If the user inputs `a = 2` and `b = 5`:

```
ans =

1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
1    5
2    1
2    2
2    3
2    4
2    5
```

For other values of `a` and `b`, the matrix should be constructed according to the above shown sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved straight-forward by the use of **[`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)** and **[`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)**:

```
[repelem((1:a).',b),repmat((1:b).',a,1)]
```

---

A more elegant way is using **[`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html)** and reshape it after:

```
[A,B] = meshgrid(1:a,1:b);
[A(:),B(:)]
```

---

Let's create an anonymous function and test the first approach:

```
>> fun = @(a,b) [repelem((1:a).',b),repmat((1:b).',a,1)];

>> fun(1,1)
ans =
     1     1

>> fun(2,2)
ans =
     1     1
     1     2
     2     1
     2     2

>> fun(2,5)
ans =
     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
     1     5
     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     2     4
     2     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way
for example  `a = 2` and `b = 5`

```
 A(1:b*a,1) = reshape(mtimes((1:a).',ones(1,b)).',1,b*a)
 A(1:b*a,2) = reshape(mtimes((1:b).',ones(1,a)),1,b*a)
A =

     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
     1     5
     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     2     4
     2     5
```

There is just one logic, in the code below you define a matrix of row size and a and column size b

```
>> mtimes((1:a).',ones(1,b))

ans =

     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
```

and the next step simply reshapes the matrix column wise for `a` and row wise for `b` by taking a transpose

```
A(1:b*a,1) = reshape(mtimes((1:a).',ones(1,b)).',1,b*a)
A(1:b*a,2) = reshape(mtimes((1:b).',ones(1,a)),1,b*a)
```